# How to include baseline 64kbps  audio?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

My one app is rejected and it says :

`Reasons for Rejection:

9.4: Video streaming content over a cellular network longer than 10 minutes must use HTTP Live and include a baseline 64 kbps audio-only HTTP Live stream`

I know how to use `HTTP Live Streaming` in my app with the use of **HTTP Live Streaming Tool** and `mediafilesegmenter` but i don't know how to include baseline 64 kbps audio-only Http Live Stream.
How can i set my audio file to the baseline 64kbps??
Can anyone please help me in this??
Thank you in advance.. !!!!

Comment: I am really new to this topic.. plz guide me in this.. It would be very helpful for me..!!!